# Sending File and JSON from Angular to Restlet

Tags: java, angularjs, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have a form that includes an object bound to the `html` with `ng-bind`. The same form includes a `fileupload` widget: `<input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile">`.

I'm submitting this to a `Java Restlet`. I am able to get the `File` in the `restlet` but the `json` that should represent my object is null. Is there a way to solve this?

Here's my code. On the angular side:

```
function saveMap2(map, fileToUpload) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("map", map);
    formData.append("file", fileToUpload);

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(REST_SAVE_MAP_URI, formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .then(
      function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
    },
    function(errResponse) {
        console.error('Error while saveMap');
        deferred.reject(errResponse);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

On the `Restlet` side:

```
@Post
public Representation doPost(Representation entity) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Media type? " + entity.getMediaType());
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(1000240);
        RestletFileUpload upload = new RestletFileUpload(factory);
        FileItemIterator fileIterator = upload.getItemIterator(entity);

        while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
               FileItemStream fi = fileIterator.next();
               String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
               String contentType = fi.getContentType();
               System.out.println("FIELD = " + fieldName + ": " + fi);
               if (!fi.isFormField()) {
                  String fileName = fi.getName();
                  System.out.println("name? " + fileName);

                  InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(fi.openStream());
                  BufferedOutputStream output = null;

                  try {
                      output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/path/" + fileName, false));
                      int data = -1;
                      while ((data = is.read()) != -1) {
                          output.write(data);
                      }
                  } finally {
                      is.close();
                      output.close();
                  }
               } 
        }
  }
```

The result is that the image I'm uploading is saved correctly, but I don't know how to get the `map` `json`.

Here's some output:

```
Media type? multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9GSUTgCJ4NbnnoT8
FIELD = map:  org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl@54d1ffff
FIELD = file: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl@5a160b15
name? IMG_5327.JPG
```

When I'm printing the `entity` it seems like the request is fine:

```
'------WebKitFormBoundarysmqftmsA0EFDlceo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="map"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundarysmqftmsA0EFDlceo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG_5327.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Any idea how to solve this? How can I get both the json and the file from the same request?

Comment: Dunno, but are you sure that the "[object Object]" in the first part of your multipart request is correct? Looks to me as if .toString has been invoked on the JS side rather than the conversation to JSON function.

Comment: I tried to use stringify but it changes nothing. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a piece of code on the restlet side to get the 'map' object and then pass it to the code that gets the file.

Comment: I don't see the Content-Type of your map form data either. Without it frameworks cannot deduce the content properly.

Comment: Well, I'm asking for help here. The code on the request (angular) side is supposed to allow for sending both json AND a file. Note the headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} header and the transform function one line above it.

Comment: If you provide an isolated case (a complete setup), I'd be willing to take a closer look.

Comment: I found a solution and posted it as an answer. Not sure it's the most elegant solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by sending the `json` object in the query, and getting it in the `restlet` by using the `HttpServletRequest` and pulling the relevant parameter from it.

Looking at the code in the question this is the modification on the `angular` side:

```
$http.post(REST_SAVE_MAP_URI + "?map=" + JSON.stringify(map), formData, {...
```

and in the `restlet`:

```
org.restlet.Request restletRequest = getRequest();
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ServletUtils.getRequest(restletRequest);
String mapJson = servletRequest.getParameter("map"));
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map map = gson.fromJson(servletRequest.getParameter("map"), Map.class);
```

Everything else on both the `restlet` and `angular` side is exactly the same.